# Hot to cut the last N characters of a file name (shell)

Tags: shell, command

Basic question: I'd like to be able to cut the name from the end (as to remove extensions or just shorten the name of files).

Thanks!
GM

To remove extension: mv "$file" "${file%.*}"
To remove N last characters: echo filename | sed 's/.{N}$//g'
(replace N by number of characters)

Comment: Is N a variable, or a fixed value? For instance for N=3, this can be done by `${filename%???}`, provided that `filename` is the variable holding the name of your file.

Comment: I just found out. Wrote the answer. But your answer works too! Thanks!

Comment: What you have, is something diffent: You don't remove the last N characters, but just the extension. This is different from the title (and, if I remember correctly, also from the original question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

echo filename   |   sed   's/.\{N\}$//g' can delete the last N character.
N could be replace by 1,2,3,etc.

Comment: > echo file | sed 's/.{4}$//g'                                                                                                     
> file / it doesnt work

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein : What do you expect from it? The word _file_ has 4 characters. You are deleting the last for, which leaves you with an empty string, and you write this to a file with the name `file`. I would expect that you have a file named `file` which just contains a single end-of-line character. What else did you expect?

Comment: @Jason_AnN : Correct, but wouldn't `echo "$filename"` be a more realistic example? Dropping the last 4 characters from `filename`, yielding just `file`, can be done manually, without the need of a program.

Comment: @user1934428:  The  "filename" is the file's real name, also could be a variable.

Comment: @Emmanuel Goldstein : the page shows wrong, it doesn't show the character "\", please add it.

Comment: @user1934428 You are absolutely right, I'm a moron. I have accepted your answer. Thanks!